# Арифметические операции в Python справа налево, а не слева направо?

Tags: python, операторы, арифметика

Простенький пример в Python вызвал у меня недоумение:

```
d = 15.961599999999999
d ** 1.5
>>>63.76973829534582
d ** 0.5 ** 3
>>>1.4137888521577402
0.5 ** 3
>>>0.125
d ** 0.125
>>>1.4137888521577402
```

Вопрос: почему Python вначале выполняет возведение `0.5 ** 3`, а уже потом `d ** (0.5 ** 3)`. Разве не должны арифметические операции выполняться слева направо? `(d ** 0.5) ** 3`

Comment: В общем случае - нет, операции не обязаны выполняться слева направо. Это вопрос соглашения. В Python видимо принято соглашение, что степень вычисляется справа налево.

Comment: Пожалуйста, всегда давайте ссылку на (и цитируйте) источник вашего утверждения, чтобы другие участники имели возможность недоумевать вместе с вами.

Comment: Буду иметь ввиду)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[из документации (Python: table of operator precedence)](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence):

> Operators in the same box group left to right (**except for
>   exponentiation, which groups from right to left**).

Answer (score 0):

Python считает правильно, сначала степень в степень возводится, а затем основание в степень. Именно по этому d ** 0.125, чтобы было так как Вы хотите поставьте скобки.